# Universal Application in Xcode 6 using Universal Storyboards

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6, ios-universal-app, universal-storyboard

i am developing an universal application using Xcode 6.0.1 universal storyboards. While using this i am confused how to configure my application for both iPhone and iPad (for all devices). I use W-Any H-Any for putting all buttons, ImageViews that i need on both iPhone and iPad. But now i am confused how to resize all this according to my views on iPhone and iPad. Basically for now I'm using the images for iPad as they are the highest resolution images i have. Can't use iPhone images for iPad views. Now if i use images of iPad they are of higher resolution and don't fit on iPhone view. Can anyone suggest me how to use different images for iPhone and iPad while using universal storyboards. And pls tell me how to use constraints to resize my view according to iPad and iPhone.

Answer (score 3):

Hey you have to use Media.xcassets.. Just you have to add the image in Media.xcassets after than storyboard will automatically take its relative image from Media.xcassets.

Comment: i haven't used it till now so can you pls help me with this. anything that will help me with this.